# LoadErrors with specifically ruby 1.8.7 on OSX 10.7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

This is on a clean install of OSX 10.7 Lion. Here's the actions I've taken:

---

I installed Xcode (4.1)

I installed RVM (1.8.0 ):

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)

$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I installed ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm install 1.9.2
```

I switch switch to 1.8.7

```
rvm use 1.8.7
```

I install a gem

```
gem install json
```

I use that gem in a ruby file.

```
require 'json'
```

I attempt to run that ruby file and get the following error:

```
main.rb.txt:1:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
```

I double check my gems:

```
gem list
```

..sure enough, it's installed.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.5.4)
rack (1.3.2)
rake (0.9.2 ruby)
sinatra (1.2.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
```

This problem presents itself regardless of what gem I require. However, if I switch to 1.9.2, everything works fine.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled ruby 1.8.7 (along with every other version) with RVM. I've uninstalled and reinstalled gems with gem. What am I missing?

Additional information:
Gem version: 1.8.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you require rubygems first? You need to require that in order to activate the gem loader in your Ruby program:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
```

Comment: Oh god that's embarrassing. How did I miss that? I guess ruby 1.9.2 is more idiot proof.

Comment: Just FYI, I was switching environments from Win to OSX and on Win you don't require rubygems. Great that I found this question, it was not so clear.

Comment: @hajder Actually since Ruby version 1.9 rubygems is loaded by default. So if you install that version on your other machine you won't need to load it separately there either.

Comment: @Casper you're right! I installed rvm on my OSX machine too. Highly recommended as hashes were not printed correctly either in 1.8